# htaccess - HTTP to HTTPS and .HTML to /

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I need help with an `.htaccess` that:

forces `http://` to `https://`

AND

forces `.html` to `/`

What I have so far:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
#1 This line checks if the https is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
#then, redirect to https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,L,R]
#2 this line checks if the request is /file.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
#then redirect /file.html to /file
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

#3 if the request is not for dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#and the request is an existing filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
#then rewrite /file to /file.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

In the example above, the first condition is met when the original scheme is HTTP, and then the rule is processed. HTTP goes to HTTPS. The first Round of rewrite processing ends here.

In the second round, mod_rewrite accepts the URI /file.html and the rule redirects it to /file, since the /file  does not exist in directory, so we need to rewrite it to the original file #3...

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I've used both of them before, but I haven't used them together. Hope this helps.

(EDIT)
To actually FORCE extensions to look like directories:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file

Comment: This is better, unfortunately /example.html isn't forcing /example

Comment: By forcing you want it to change their URL from /anything.html to /anything or just anything/ or anything.html will both work?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure `mod-rewrite` is enabled.
Then, put this code in your htaccess (which should be in document root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect http urls to https equivalent
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect existing /path/file.html to /path/file/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite back /path/file/ to /path/file.html (if existing)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

**Warning**:

1. Make sure to serve the same document root as http for https (apache ssl block configuration)
2. Be aware that this creates virtual directories (by adding a trailing
   slash) which could mess up your html resources (if you're using
   relative paths instead of absolute paths). If so, use absolute paths
   instead