# Redirect all URLs starting with https:// to same URLs starting with http://

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been looking for this solution but can't get it anywhere.

I have a website (shop) with SSL set up on it, working fine except in the area where customers would get an URL to the file they just purchased.

So, my working url to a download file should look something like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?eddfile=123456etc
```

But the files only work if you browse them without HTTPS prefix:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?eddfile=123456etc
```

So what I need is just to remove the https from these URLs that start with:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?eddfile
```

And redirect them to the same URLs but without https prefix rather with regular prefix:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?eddfile
```

Note: this is not a regular https to http (or vice versa) redirection for which I found answers here - Although this should be a simple .htaccess redirection, I need to make sure that this only happens to the urls that are beginning as described above

I tried to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} eddfile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]
```

But no success with that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess - HTTP to HTTPS & .HTML to /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114290/htaccess-http-to-https-html-to)

Comment: @Marcin this is not a duplicate of that Q&A

Comment: (On Apache) There is no clean system level way of going *from* `HTTPS` *to* `HTTP`. If you need to do this, it is almost certain that you're trying to resolve a symptom rather than actually fix the issue at hand. Research why some parts of your site don't work on HTTPS and resolve that. Staying back in the stone age and not using HTTPS is ***NOT*** the answer.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the reply. Yes you're right, it is a kind of a desperate move to solve an issue. All of the rest of the website works pretty well on HTTPS except these files - if you have any ideas how I could force these URL files to work on HTTPS that would be awesome. I'm on WordPress with Eeasy Digital Downloads plugin. Thanks

Comment: "the files only work if" - What actually happens when you do try to access these URLs via HTTPS? (Bit of an aside, but rather than redirecting, could you not simply link directly to the HTTP URL? Presumably if the HTTP URL works then you don't have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect anywhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin suggests in comments, the real solution would be to fix why your HTTPS URL does "not work". (But also, why not just link directly to the HTTP URL if that "works"?)

Anyway, to answer your specific question... try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^eddfile=.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This is only a "temporary" (302) redirect, since this is only a "temporary" fix.

`eddfile` is part of the query string, not the URL-path. The query string is automatically passed through to the *substitution*, providing you don't provide a query string.

Since you say the HTTP URL "works" then I assume you don't have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect?? Otherwise, you would need to include an exception with this redirect in order to avoid a redirect loop.

Comment: I am using a plugin which generates these URLs so it is not a single link, it is plenty of them - these are unique links generated for file downloads.

I have set up SSL for my website and it works pretty fine except these files - somehow they're not redirected to HTTPS (File not found error gets loaded instead) - and once I manually just remove the "s" from the https prefix I get the file.

If there' is a way that I could specifically force these files with the eddfile query string to be properly redirected to HTTPS that would be awesome.

Tried the code above and didn't get any results

Comment: "somehow they're not redirected to HTTPS (File not found error gets loaded instead)" - "File not found"?! But when you request the HTTP version of this link, you presumably don't get a "File not found" error? "If there' is a way that I could specifically force these files with the eddfile query string to be properly redirected to HTTPS that would be awesome." - But you are trying to redirect to HTTP in your question?? The code above did nothing? Did you place it near the top of your `.htaccess` file? The order is important.

Comment: Ah just added it to the top of the .htaccess file and it works perfectly.
You saved my day!
Thanks a lot